# If $A$ is bounded then so is $A\cdot A$?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

im struggling to prove the following problem.

Let $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ be a non empty set, (multipication is for example $A\cdot B= \{a \cdot b\ |\ a \in A,\ b \in B\}$)

Show: If $A$ is bounded, then $A\cdot A$ is bounded too!

I know that from the completenes axiom the set A has an infimum and a supremum. what should I do next . I'm new to this material and i dont understand it to it's fullest.

pls help, thanks

Comment: Do you mean $A \subset \Bbb R$? Because $\{ a | a\in \Bbb R \} = \Bbb R$ so this wouldn’t make much sense since $\Bbb R$ is unbounded

Comment: yes that is what i meant

Comment: $|ab|=|a||b| <M \cdot M= M^2$, where $M$ is a bound for $A$.

Comment: @GhostAmarth the supremum of $[-1,0]$ is $0$, but $1 \in [-1,0]\cdot [-1,0]$ which is bigger than $(\sup [-1,0])^2 = 0$.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Whoops... That’s a good point! Was a bit in a hurry when is posted it

Answer (score 1):

If a $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is bounded then there exists a positive number $r \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that $A$ is contained in the ball $B_r(0)$ with radius $r$ centered in $0$.
Clearly,
$$
A\cdot A \subseteq B_r(0) \cdot B_r(0) \subseteq B_{r^2}(0).
$$
For the last inclusion take $x,y \in B_r(0)$. Then we have $|x|, |y| < r$, which implies
$$|x\cdot y| = |x|\cdot |y| < r\cdot r.$$
So $A\cdot A$ is bounded by $r^2$.

This proof can be easily reused for bounded sets in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I Don' t understand the thing with the ball .

Comment: Which thing? The definition of a ball is $B_r(0) := \{x \in \mathbb{R} : |x| < r \}$. This may seem like an overkill because you can also just write $(-r,r)$.

Comment: Calling the interval a [ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)#In_general_metric_spaces) is incredibly common in literature because it generalizes nicely to higher dimensions.  In $\Bbb R^3$ you would have a ball of radius $r$ centered around a point $p$ would be the set $\{x\in\Bbb R^3:\|x-p\|<r\}$.  Yes, in the case of $\Bbb R^1$ balls and intervals are the same thing, but the naming comes from how it appears in $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ and higher.

Comment: can someone explain to me the thing with the absolute value ?

Comment: @AvivBarel again which thing? you should try to ask your question more precisely!